# Angular 9: How to pass event in property? Invoking event tells allways 'is not a function'

Tags: angular

In component "xx" we try to ask some values in common dialog. Dialog has own service, where we pass tData.

Tried these syntax and many other for event clickedOK:

```
{

    tData["clickedOK"]=this.delObj.bind(this);

    tData["clickedOK"]=this.delObj;
    
    tData["clickedOK"]=function(obj) {this.delObj(obj)};

    tData["clickedOK"]=function(obj) {this.delObj(obj).bind(this)};

    tData["clickedOK"]=function(obj) {this.delObj(obj)}.bind(this);
}

delObj(obj: any): void {
    
  //***some code***
}
```

Thse are in component "xx".

And tData is passed to dialog service, where we are invoking it this way:

```
  this.getData().clickedOK.emit(newData);
```

But get allways

ERROR TypeError: this.getData(...).clickedOK.emit is not a function
at ComponentDialogService.push../src/app/services/component-dialog.service.ts.ComponentDialogService.btnClickedOK (component-dialog.service.ts:26)

What is the right syntax to set clickedOK?

Comment: The value you are supplying for `tData["clickedOK"]` is a function. So the error message is correct, `clickedOK.emit` is not a function, but `clickedOK` itself is. So you need to call it directly like `this.getData().clickedOK(newData);`.

Comment: If you hover over this  "tdata.clickedOk "  then right click, and go to definition; do you see an EventEmitter?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse! Thanks.